# Data structure in which only one item is special at a time?

Tags: data-structures, computer-science

THE QUESTION:
Is there a name for a data structure in which only one item can be "active" or "highlighted at a time?

MORE INFO:
Javascript is my language of choice, but this is more for curiosity's sake than anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Queues, stacks and heaps have this property.
- Streams and iterators allow access to a single item at a time only, but I wouldn't call them data structures.
- APIs following this concept are sometimes called "cursor-based".